# How to add Bash or PowerShell script to Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I'm quite new to CI and am experimenting with Azure DevOps.

I want to use an automated testing tool in my CI pipeline that uses either a Bash script and a PowerShell script that's run inside the CI pipeline to trigger the testing tool.

How do I add either the Bash or PowerShell script into my pipeline in Azure DevOps so that the script runs and triggers the testing tool?

Answer (score 5):

There are built-in [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops)/[Bash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops) tasks that you can add to your pipeline.

You can add `.ps1` or `.sh` to your repository and in the task specify the script file, or put an inline script.

If you using `.yaml` builds you can add them in this way:

```
# PowerShell
# Run a PowerShell script on Windows, macOS, or Linux.
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    #targetType: 'filePath' # Optional. Options: filePath, inline
    #filePath: # Required when targetType == FilePath
    #arguments: # Optional
    #script: '# Write your powershell commands here.' # Required when targetType == Inline
    #errorActionPreference: 'stop' # Optional. Options: stop, continue, silentlyContinue
    #failOnStderr: false # Optional
    #ignoreLASTEXITCODE: false # Optional
    #pwsh: false # Optional
    #workingDirectory: # Optional

# Bash
# Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    #targetType: 'filePath' # Optional. Options: filePath, inline
    #filePath: # Required when targetType == FilePath
    #arguments: # Optional
    #script: '# Write your commands here# Use the environment variables input below to pass secret variables to this script' # Required when targetType == Inline
    #workingDirectory: # Optional
    #failOnStderr: false # Optional
    #noProfile: true # Optional
    #noRc: true # Optional
```

If you using the visual designer you can add the tasks in this way:

[image]

[image]